# Call from docker ui container to api container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose

```
services:
  api:
    image: api
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    external_links:
      - front
    networks:
      - global
  front:
    image: front
    container_name: front
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    external_links:
      - api
    networks:
      - global

networks:
   global:
```

I'm trying to call api from ui container.
Here is the call url: http://api:3000/api/search?query=ihpone&page=1&minPrice=0&maxPrice=9999
I'm getting error ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Someone can help me ? How to solve my issue. How make request from ui container to api container?

Comment: Are you trying to call the API from the UI container, or from a browser application hosted by the UI container?  Why do you have `external_links:` there; does removing them help?  (Similarly you can delete all of the `container_name:` and manual `networks:` setup and use Compose’s default setup here.)

Comment: from a browser application hosted by the UI container.

Comment: You need to use the host’s IP address and a `ports:` published port number.  The browser can never access the Docker-internal host names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're opening your UI application on browser you're actually downloading it to host (your machine where docker is installed) and then you're making a call to API.

So in your example you need to set url in your UI application's configuration to be: **localhost:3000** instead of **api:3000**

- **localhost:3000** - is to hit an app in a docker container from a host.
- **api:3000** - is to hit an app in a docker container from another docker container.